# How would one edit a params/parameters attribute before validation or save in the Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### Short question...

How do I edit an attribute passed to the model before validation or save?

---

### Long question...

In my app I have a unique number generator so that entries can be indexed on an randomly generated unique number, so that users can not find that entry (In other words an alternative to using ID, which a user can randomly guess).

So in my model I have...

```
def self.generate_photo_number
  record = Object.new
  while record
    random = rand(9223372036854775806)
    record = Photo.first(:conditions => ["unique_photo_no = ?", random])
  end
  return random
end
```

And in my forms I have the input...

```
<%= hidden_field(:photo, :unique_photo_no, value: Photo.generate_photo_number) %>
i.e.
<input id="photo_unique_photo_no" name="photo[unique_photo_no]" type="hidden" value="233720368547758" />
```

Thing is, if the user submits the form, presses the back button, changes an option and submits again, the rails app will find an entry with that same `unique_photo_no` and cause a save error.

I could create a JavaScript function that generates a number on clicking submit (which I have done for pages outside the Rails app environment), but the beauty with the `generate_photo_number` function is that it checks to make sure it does not already exist - whereas the JavaScript does not.

How can I generate the number before validation and save it in the `unique_photo_no` attribute?

This is what I have put so far in my Photo model...

```
before_validation :generate_photo_number

validates_uniqueness_of :unique_photo_no,
                        :message => " - is already in use."

def self.generate_photo_number
  record = Object.new
  while record
    random = rand(9223372036854775806)
    record = Photo.first(:conditions => ["unique_photo_no = ?", random])
  end
  @photo.unique_photo_no = random
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to edit the attribute once it has passed to the Model.

Instead, edit the attribute before it is passed to the Model from the Controller.

---

For this question example, do the following...

1. Remove the form input field for `unique_photo_no`, as it is no longer needed
2. Add this to the 'create' action only of the Photos controller, beneath the @photo instance variable. Do not add it to the 'update' action, otherwise a new number will be generated each time it is updated.

> ```
> def create
>   @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
>
>   @photo.unique_photo_no = Photo.generate_photo_number
>
>   .
>   .
>   .
> end
> ```

Photo(being the Model).generate_photo_number(being the function called)

Answer (score 0):

Rails `callbacks NOT a CLASS method`  so you need to remove self in your model than i hope it will work.

if you want to validate the data while creating a new record mean you can use `before_create callbacks`

for your before validation callback should be in

```
before_validation :generate_photo_number

validates_uniqueness_of :unique_photo_no,
                        :message => " - is already in use."

def generate_photo_number
  record = Object.new
  while record
    random = rand(9223372036854775806)
    record = Photo.first(:conditions => ["unique_photo_no = ?", random])
  end
  self.unique_photo_no = random
end
```

it will automatically call when your hitting save or update.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work `undefined method 'unique_photo_no=' for nil:NilClass`. So the solution is to edit or state `@photo.unique_photo_no` in the Controller before it hits the Model. Anyway, calling `self` should be fine. Before I started trying to be fancy, using `self` worked; It is only saying 'myself', as in this case 'Photo'

Comment: Ha, works! Thanks, did not think it were possible. In this case I had to remove the `.self` from the beginning of `generate_photo_number`. But it does not work for `before_create` callbacks, because it validates the data before it reaches 'create'. Is there a callback for validating before, but on the 'create' action only? I have tried `before_validation(on: :create) do...` [source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)